# Manage ASP.NET Web Service Source Code

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2005, version-control

I'm working on building a set of ASP.NET (2.0) web-services to be deployed into a single web application under IIS7. The services will be added incrementally (over a period of a year or more) by multiple programmers. How should I organize my source in VS2005.

- Should I use one project or several?
- Should I use a Web-Application or Web-Site project.
- How do I manage the web.config that they will all share.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use source control now? All of your "control" problems are solved by any decent source control system (i.e., not VSS).

I'd put them into a single project assuming they have code and types in common between them. For instance, if they use the same data access layer and underlying database.

I would never use web site "projects" for web services. Any of their advantages are advantages for web sites made up of web pages, and not for the more complex requirements of web services.

Answer (score 1):

I'll speak to how our shop handles this, which I find to work well.

We use several projects.  One for each web service.  This allows us to publish one service without effecting the others. We're also on VSS (bleck!) which makes for less conflicts.

We use a Web-Site project and it works fine

We manage the web.config by doing a diff on the file before we publish.  The web.config's are something that rarely change